# Subsonic 3 Foreign Key with Class relationship issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, subsonic3

i´m using LINQ with the subsonic in a class to get my data here is the code below:

```
public IQueryable<Veiculo> SelecionaVeiculosSite() 
        {
                   return (from v in _db.Veiculos
                            where v.Ativo == true &&
                            v.Marca.Ativo == true && 
                            v.Modelo.Ativo == true
                            select v
                           );            

        }
```

You will see one difference in line at "v.Marca.Ativo == true", I did one modification in template of ActiveRecord to get a  and not a IQueryable. That the way i founded to make Classes relations based on the Foreign Keys of my database.

This is the code modified in the template (generated):

```
public Marca Marca
        {
            get
            {

                  var repo=OKMMySql.Marca.GetRepo();
                  return (from items in repo.GetAll()
                       where items.ID_Marca == _ID_Marca
                       select items).SingleOrDefault();
            }
        }
```

in the Code it´s ok, but this Select return this Execution time Error:

> The binary operator Equal is not
>   defined for the types
>   'System.Nullable`1[System.Int32]' and
>   'System.Int32'.

Anybody have any idea or anything to help my with this?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of your columns is nullable, it would seem.  Go look in the class generated and see which one it is, or look at your database schema.

If it doesn't need to be nullable, then just remove that from the column and re-run the .tt file.

Comment: This is not a solution. If you require a nullable relationship then the problem still exists.

Comment: Wow, revisiting old comments.  Of course it is still an issue if it needs to be nullabe.  Hence the "If it doesn't need to be nulalble".  If it does, at that point in time, I don't think there was solution.  <sigh>, but thanks for pointing out the obvious.

Comment: The solution in retrospect would be something like `where items.ID_Marca != null && items.ID_Marca.Value == _ID_Marca`, although I don't know how well subsonic would handle the conversion to SQL (you may have to pull it into code first with a `ToList()` which isn't that helpful).

Comment: I stopped using subsonic because of issues like this, and performance.  It seem like I was able to fix them all myself, in not too much time, but it has been years now and I think nothing has changed much with the project.  Kinda gave up on it, even though it was promising.

Answer (score 0):

Andrew,

this works for me i just put NotNull FLAG in the INT fields in the Database and it´s solve this BUG for me

Many Thanks